# HOW? multiSelectOptionsUpdate JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I use this library (http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-multiSelect/demo/) for creating a multiple-select dropdown. I want to update the list of options, and I see that a method exists called `multiSelectOptionsUpdate(JSON)`, but I can't find a way to use it.

I have tried this:

```
var myOptions = {
    "Value 1" : "Text 1",
    "Value 2" : "Text 2",
    "Value 3" : "Text 3"
};

$("#DropDownList3").multiSelectOptionsUpdate(myOptions);
```

...But I haven't had any luck.

Can anyone help me use this?

```
// Update the dropdown options
multiSelectOptionsUpdate: function(options) {
    buildOptions.call($(this), options);
},
```

Comment: I solve this by doing like this:

    function test2() {
      var options = [];
      options.push({ text: "Value 1", value: "Text 1", selected:"selected" });
      options.push({ text: "Value 2", value: "Text 3", selected:"" });
      $("#DropDownList3").multiSelectOptionsUpdate(options);
    }

Comment: Gud. post this as answer and accept it. May be it will help someone in future....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by doing like this:

```
   function test2() { 
var options = []; 
options.push({  text: "Value 1", value: "Text 1", selected:"selected" }); 
options.push({  text: "Value 2", value: "Text 3", selected:"" }); $("#DropDownList3").multiSelectOptionsUpdate(options); 
}
```